# After update to MacOs Mojave Visual Studio Code text is almost unreadable (dimmed)

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, atom-editor, macos-mojave

I have just installed MacOs Mojave... And when I opened Visual Studio Code... Surprise! The text it's kind of dimmed with less contrast, specially on the external display. The result is that the code it's hard to read. It seemed related to the mode, but not! It happens both in Light and dark modes.

[image]

Has anyone found a solution to that problem?

Comment: Seems related to this issue:
https://ahmadawais.com/fix-macos-mojave-font-rendering-issue/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, I end up finding the solution thanks to [Ahmad Awais post](https://ahmadawais.com/fix-macos-mojave-font-rendering-issue/). It is a font rendering issue that affects to many ElectronJS based apps.

1. Open the terminal and execute

   ```
   defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool FALSE
   ```
2. Restart the system

Comment: Mentioned in the v1.28 release notes: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_miscellaneous A slightly different command is given there, I assume both work.

Comment: I would describe my font as dimmed rather than blurry. Are we all talking about the same thing?

Comment: Probably. I also described it as dimmed.